# How to improve performance when loading CSV file into html table with javascript and ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, csv

Im using this code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wuvqbsupfc27iaq/systemSK.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
  }).done(hovory);

  function hovory(data) {
    var promenna = data.replace(/\n/g,";").split(";");
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < promenna.length; i+=32) {
        var line = [];
        line.push(promenna[i+0]);
        line.push(promenna[i+1]);
        line.push(promenna[i+14]);
        line.push(promenna[i+15]);
        line.push(promenna[i+16]);
        line.push(promenna[i+25]);
        line.push(promenna[i+26]);
        line.push(promenna[i+27]);
        result.push(line);
    }


    for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i+=1){
    var radek = '<tr>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][0] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][1] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][2] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][3] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][4] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][5] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][6] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '<td>' + result[i][7] + '</td>';
    radek +=  '</tr>';
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("tabulka");
    theDiv.innerHTML += radek;
    }
  };
});
```

I basically load the csv from Dropbox, create array from it and appends table. It works, but its very slow look at my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XjOyYE?editors=1010

If you set at for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i+=1) i+= at 7 table appends immediately. If to 1, then takes some time until table appends.

Is there a way how to append my table quicker? What creates that delay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your major problem comes from constant DOM manipulation, you must avoid adding it every row once it is a very large amout of data, otherwize will result in a large amout of DOM operations which is very expensive. I reduced the time of the rendering loop just by moving the table outside the loop and then adding the entire table once from `4210.902ms` to `36.266ms`, as you can see, it's a huge difference.

Also, you can reduce the loops to only one, in this case, there is no need to use two loops. You can split the `rows` by line breaks (i.e. `\n`), and columns by semicolon (`;`) and build your table within the process.

**UPDATE 1**

By reusing the main loop I could reduce the hovory time from `229.830ms` to `23.405ms`.

Original:

```
ajax: 1713.042ms
promenna: 3.281ms
for1: 6.031ms
for html: 4240.323ms
hovory: 4251.732ms
```

After reduce DOM operations:

```
ajax: 2001.135ms
promenna: 4.595ms
for1: 2.395ms
for html: 19.575ms
hovory: 229.830ms
```

After reuse the main loop to render the html:

```
ajax: 658.290ms
hovory: 23.405ms
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  console.time('ajax');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wuvqbsupfc27iaq/systemSK.csv',
    dataType: 'text',
  }).done(function (data) {
    
    console.timeEnd('ajax');
    console.time('hovory');
    hovory(data);    
    console.timeEnd('hovory');
  });

  function hovory(data) {
    
    var rows = data.split('\n').map(function (row) {
      row = row.split(';');
      
      var radek = '<tr>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[0] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[1] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[14] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[15] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[16] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[25] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[26] + '</td>';
      radek += '<td>' + row[27] + '</td>';
      radek += '</tr>';
      
      return radek;
    }).join('');
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("tabulka");
    theDiv.innerHTML = rows;    
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabulka"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code using some imporovements:

- caching an array length in `l` variable within `for` statement
- inserting HTML elements into `documentFragment` which is appended to DOM at the end (without constant calculations in UI)

  ```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/wuvqbsupfc27iaq/systemSK.csv',
      dataType: 'text',
    }).done(hovory);

    function hovory(data) {
      var promenna = data.replace(/\n/g,";").split(";");
      var theDiv = document.getElementById("tabulka");
      var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), tr, td;
      var result = [];

      for(var i = 0, l = promenna.length; i < l; i+=32) {
          var line = [];
          line.push(promenna[i+0]);
          line.push(promenna[i+1]);
          line.push(promenna[i+14]);
          line.push(promenna[i+15]);
          line.push(promenna[i+16]);
          line.push(promenna[i+25]);
          line.push(promenna[i+26]);
          line.push(promenna[i+27]);
          result.push(line);
      }

      for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i+=1) {
          tr = document.createElement('tr');
          for (var j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {
              td = document.createElement('td');
              td.textContent = result[i][j];
              tr.appendChild(td);
          }
          frag.appendChild(tr);
          theDiv.appendChild(frag);
      }
    };
  });
  ```

Comment: But this not load my table, look what loads my code and yours. It seems that yours only loads first array.

Answer (score 0):

// hello you can simplify your code like that :

```
function hovory(data) {
    var radek='';
    var tb=data.split("\n");
    tb.forEach(function(ligne) {
        if (ligne !="") {
            var lgn=ligne.split(";");
            radek += '<tr>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[0] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[1] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[14] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[15] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[16] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[25] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[26] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '<td>' + lgn[27] + '</td>';
            radek +=  '</tr>';
        }  
    });
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("tabulka");
    theDiv.innerHTML += radek;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's 'expensive' to generated DOM tables with all the data. Your CSV is not that big but if you want performance I recommend you to use [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) for lazy loading.

To load CSV data there is also a great library ('Multithread') called [Papaparse](http://papaparse.com) which will speed up your program for sure.