# jQuery get big csv to html table

Tags: jquery

I want to to make a big csv to html table.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('cases.csv', function(data) {

var html = "<table class='table' id='table'>";

var rows = data.split("\n");

// parse lines
var max = 10000;
var num = 0;
rows.forEach( function getvalues(ourrow) {
if (num < max) {
    num ++;
    if(num == 1){
        html += "<thead>";
    }
    html += "<tr>";

    var columns = ourrow.split(",");

    html += "<td>" + columns[0] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[1] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[2] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[3] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[4] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[5] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[6] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[7] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[8] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[9] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[10] + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + columns[11] + "</td>";

    html += "</tr>";
    if(num == 1){
        html += "</thead>";
    }
} else {
    return false;
}

})
html += "</table>";

console.log(html);

$('#container-fluid').html(html);
$('#table').DataTable();

});


</script>
```

Its working, but only cause i limit the "max" to 10000. If i get higher, it doesnt load and browser/tab crashed.

Is there a way to load 10000 after 10000... So first 10000, than next 10000 or something?

The CSV has over 900000 Rows and gets much more in short time

I already tried other scripts but the most crashed before and also cannot run that.

I only want to show the csv in a nice html table.

// 
I already tried also [How to improve performance when loading CSV file into html table with javascript and ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217150/how-to-improve-performance-when-loading-csv-file-into-html-table-with-javascript) 
But this is also not working. Its loading and loading and than also browser died

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to improve performance when loading CSV file into html table with javascript and ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217150/how-to-improve-performance-when-loading-csv-file-into-html-table-with-javascript)

Comment: What happens if you comment out `$('#table').DataTable();` ? You can also use datatables to paginate and pass in an array. https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html So you won't have to build out the table/html manually.

Comment: agillgilla that is what i tried, but thats not working, think to big csv

Comment: Why would you ever need to render 900000 rows? That is crazy and no user can absorb anywhere near that many rows. Use pagination. Datatables or other table script that accepts data directly would be your best bet

Comment: Probably crashes because of running out of memory or timing out because its taking too long.  Go with @charlietfl's suggestion and use pagination, or if you _need_ everything on one page, try loading the content dynamically after the page loads initially, and adding it to the end.  Not sure if this would work for 900000 rows though, it still might crash or at least get really slow

Comment: 900000 rows, even if there's only 100 chars in each row, it is 90mb. It is surely to make browsers irresponsive or crash and on top of that the ajax call is supposed to fail(get disconnected) if loading time takes too long. You can create an api like endpoint on the serverside which will serve paginated csv data rows when your script calls it with pagintion params(i.e- offset, limit).

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you seriously consider @Tank's excellent proposal. You don't need to set up any HTML but the `table` tags. DataTables will do all the rest for you, including memory management and pagination. Have a good look at the link he included, and you will see this for yourself.